# How to auto scroll/pan Oxyplot after it has more than a set maximum points?

Tags: wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I'm using the following LinearAxis as my X-Axis, I'd like to set the minimum as 0 and maximum as 300. But in some situation, the X-Axis can go beyond 300. In that case, I want the x-axis to auto scroll.

```
<oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" MajorGridlineStyle="Dot" Title="seconds"
                       MinWidth="100"     Minimum="0" Maximum="300"   
IsPanEnabled="True"  ></oxy:LinearAxis>
```

I know that if I don't set Minimum or Maximum, the axis is actually auto-scaling, but it auto-scales from the very beginning regardless of the set maximum value, which is not what I want.

Any setting should I try on the LinearAxis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `Series` to `ObservableCollection<DataPoint>` and handle `CollectionChanged` event. Something like this:

```
((ObservableCollection<DataPoint>)Points1).CollectionChanged += PlotPointsChanged;
((ObservableCollection<DataPoint>)Points2).CollectionChanged += PlotPointsChanged;
//...
```

in which

```
 void PlotPointsChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double max = 300;
       foreach (OxyPlot.Wpf.Series ser in oxyp.Series) 
            foreach (DataPoint dp in ser.ItemsSource)
                if (dp.X > max)
                    max = dp.X;
        botAxis.Maximum = max;
    }
```

please note that *oxyp* is the name of the `Plot` and *botAxis* is the axis you are using.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works. I thought there might be some simple settings as to the axis, but changing the min/max seems to be a working solution.